# USB connection Galaxy Nexus Mac OS not working

Tags: android, galaxy-nexus

of all my devices i test to using eclipse..

my Samsung galaxy nexus is the only one that does not seem to connect to my mac..

i tried installing the android file transfer software but this did not help..

when i check in adb for devices it does not show up either..

USB debugging is enabled.

Comment: Have you tried using a different USB cable, a different USB port, and a different computer? The idea is to rule out hardware failures.

Comment: I agree, I have never had a problem with an unlocked Galaxy Nexus connection, and would hope that VZW/Sprint ports would act the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my cable was fine.. needed a better flashed ROM.. bumped up to Vicious-JellyBean-V5